# Finding an object that contains multiple objects in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

Consider the following, using Realm Swift:

```
class Shelf : Object {
 dynamic var products: List<Product>  
}
```

and:

```
class Product : Object {
 dynamic var string: String = ""

 let Shelves = LinkingObjects(fromType: Shelf.self, property: "products")
}
```

Now the question is, is it possible to perform a query like:

"What are all the shelves that contains product A and product B?"

The more general question is how to query for an objects that contain a subset of objects in it's array/list property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the correct syntax for Realm `List` properties is:

```
class Shelf: Object {
    let products = List<Product>()
}
```

Beyond that, it should be possible to query the single parent of multiple linked objects using dot notation in the `.filter` method:

```
let shelves = realm.objects(Shelf.self).filter("ANY products.string = 'A' AND ANY products.string = 'B'")
```

For more information about the types of queries you can do, check out the [`NSPredicate` page on Realm's website](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/).